# LESS File Extension Variable

Tags: jquery, css, less

Is it possible to set a file extension variable using LESS?

Here's the basic rundown of what I've got going on.

I'm using sprites for my background images and using SVG as my filetype, works like a charm. However, it obviously doesn't work in IE8-.

I'm using a great check in Modernizr that replaces .svg extensions with .png extensions if the browser doesn't support it:

```
if (!Modernizr.svg) {
    jQuery('img[src$=".svg"]').each(function()
    {
        jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('.svg', '.png'));
    });
}
```

The problem is that for my sprite mixin I'm using:

```
@sprite-Grid: 23px;
.sprite(@x, @y) {
    background: url(../img/sprite.svg) no-repeat;
    background-position: -(@x*@sprite-Grid) -(@y*@sprite-Grid);
}
```

And the great little image replacement script doesn't apply to background images, only  tags.

Ideally, what I'm looking to do is create a LESS variable that would work something like this:

**jQuery**

```
if (!Modernizr.svg) {
    jQuery('img[src$=".svg"]').each(function()
    {
        jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('.svg', '.png'));
    });


    less.modifyVars({
        '@filetype': 'png'
    });
} else {
    less.modifyVars({
        '@filetype': 'svg'
    });
}
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    .sprite(0,0,@filetype);
}

@sprite-Grid: 23px;
.sprite(@x, @y, @filetype) {
    background: url(../img/sprite.@filetype) no-repeat;
    background-position: -(@x*@sprite-Grid) -(@y*@sprite-Grid);
}
```

In short, I'd like to create a variable that gets passed and is dependent on whether or not the browser supports SVGs. If it does then it changes it to "sprite.svg" and if it doesn't it changes it to "sprite.png"

Is this even a thing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Modernizr adds classes to the `html` element for properties supported, and in this case is adding the `svg` class, it seems like the easiest way to handle the switch in LESS is to do this in your mixin:

```
.sprite(@x, @y) {
    background: url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -(@x*@sprite-Grid) -(@y*@sprite-Grid);
    .svg & {
       background: url(../img/sprite.svg) no-repeat;
    }
}
```

Then when it is used (assuming here `@sprite-Grid: 23px;`), this LESS:

```
.testClass {
  .sprite(10,10);
}
```

Produces this CSS:

```
.testClass {
  background: url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: -230px -230px;
}
.svg .testClass {
  background: url(../img/sprite.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

So it appends the `.svg` class selector above the whole chain of your selectors, thereby overriding the `png` with the `svg` when it is available. This is going to increase your overall size on the CSS file, but does allow the LESS file to be precompiled and prevents you from having to replace the path on the fly for the background images.

Comment: Thanks! This worked except that the background-position needs to be redefined with the .svg & section.

Comment: That's easy enough to add. I didn't know that for the illustration purposes, but at least you have the concept to work with.

Comment: Yeah it was just one line to add - no biggie at all. Thanks for your help.